# Socket.io: How to format the code in socket.io.js

Tags: javascript, formatting, socket.io

I am trying to understand the code in socket.io.js

For example, some snippet is here:

```
!function(e){"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=e():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(e):"undefined"!=typeof window?window.io=e():"undefined"!=typeof global?global.io=e():"undefined"!=typeof self&&(self.io=e())}(function(){var define,module,exports;
return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

module.exports = require('./lib/');

},{"./lib/":2}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
```

It is not formatted. I cannot figure it out.
What way can help it?

Comment: that is the min file you have. try the developer version of socket.io

Comment: What does "min file" mean? Where to find the developer version? I googled, but did not find the one.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js

Comment: Thanks. In the link you provided, it is almost the same: very hard to understand the beginning part of the file. Don't know the whole structure. For example, which function will be executed?